# Removing and copying files slow on NFS folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I have a server that hosts images and allows access to one directory for one client over NFS.
The directory contains about 70K images and is 12GB big.

When I execute commands like `cp` or `rm` on the server that hosts the NFS directory performance is stellar, but when execute the `cp` or `rm` from the client on the NFS directory  commands sometimes get really slow where the `real time` is slow and `user` and `sys` times are fast:

```
real    1m33.409s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

My assumptions are:

1. The directory gets somehow locked thus causing the long wait
2. The connection between the two servers is somehow not reliable

Here's a dump from the client's `nfsstat -c`

```
Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
3018431    1          3018571
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try the `noatime` option when mounting the remote filesystem in the client.

From `man 8 mount`

```
noatime  -  Do not update inode access times on this 
filesystem (e.g., for faster access on the news  spool
to speed up news servers).
```

In my case, it improved write performance a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration:

Try to export using async instead of sync. This way you won't be waiting for acknowledgment of each command issued (think of the impact this may have to data integrity in your situation).

Networking:

1. Make sure both links are running full-duplex and that jumbo frames
   are enabled throughout your network if possible. Make sure all
   devices and switches have the same settings or you'll have
   fragmentation issues.
2. Check for UDP fragmentation using Wireshark or another tool.

**Sources**

1. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/performance.html
2. http://lists.samba.org/archive/linux/2006-October/016332.html
3. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS_Troubleshooting